# Calculating Yearly Average by current month

Tags: excel

I need to create a SS that calculates the yearly average from January until the end of the previous month.

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66SPB.jpg)

[image]

Currently I have =SUM(A2:G2)/12 and each month I go in an change the range, but  I would like it to update each month to include the month that just finished.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the numbers for current and later months always 1000?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm")="Jan",0,SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:L2,,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm"),$A$1:$L$1,0)-1))/12)
```

Alternate:

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,0,SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:L2,,MONTH(TODAY())-1))/12)
```

Comment: Just for sake of fun, alternative: `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MONTH(TODAY()),4),"1","")&"2"))` :)....not taking into account when it's january.

Comment: @JvdV except that the OP wants it always divided by 12 and Address is volatile where INDEX is not.

Comment: @ScottCraner, dangit! Overlooked that `/12` :). So my attempt would look like: `=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MONTH(TODAY()),4),"1","")&"2"))/12`

Answer (score 1):

If laid out as shown above:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,A2,OFFSET(A2,,MONTH(TODAY())-2))
```

I am adding minus 2 to go to prior month and Aggregate function to allow me to specify to ignore any error values.